# Invalid int: "res/color/abc_primary_text_material_light.xml"

Tags: java, android

When using the following XML attribute on an ImageView

```
android:tint="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
```

the app crashes on some devices with this stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/color/abc_primary_text_material_light.xml"
   at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
   at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
   at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
at android.support.v7.wid
```

Why is that so? Is there any solution/workaround?

Comment: _crashes on some devices_: is there a big difference between API levels? You are pointing to a non public value and some Android version might not have that value (generally older versions).

Comment: @MateiRadu is there any other way to get the color of the primary text?

Comment: @Blackbelt my `values/colors.xml` is empty, since I don't override or set any custom color so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a private resource that could not be available on some API levels.

It's standard to define your colors in `res/values/colors.xml` like in the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="textColorPrimary">#212121</color>

    <!-- other colors -->
</resources>
```

You can then reference that color as follows:

```
android:tint="@color/textColorPrimary"
```

Comment: What if I want to get the current theme's textColorPrimary without overriding it?

Comment: You could use a different name to define your custom color and use it where you prefer. This way other text elements that do not have explicitly defined the tint or foreground will continue to use the theme color.

Comment: Or if you want some android standard defined colors you can check [this](https://material.google.com/style/color.html#color-text-background-colors) official portion of the guide and use them to define your colors.

Comment: The problem is that the app theme gets changed at runtime, and I want to tint some icons with the current theme's textColorPrimary